# Provider Hosted App – Upload Files using CSOM

Tags: office-365

I am using CSOM to send a file from a form to Share Point list. Here is my code,It says "the name file does not exist in the current context"
Any ideas?

```
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
    newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file.FileName);
    newFile.Url = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

    List docs = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List_Name");
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
    clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: <asp:FileUpload ID="UserCV" runat="server" />

Comment: Instead of file I wrote UserCV.Filename and it works

Comment: Id is `UserCV` and in your code you are using `file`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24461/discussion-between-nedia-sahraoui-and-amal-hashim).

Answer (score 1):

You can using wrong id

```
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(UserCV.FileName);
newFile.Url = Path.GetFileName(UserCV.FileName);

List docs = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List_Name");
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: It shows : Server Error in '/App' Application.
Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\new Client ID.txt'.

Comment: It is a different error than the one reported in your question. Please post it as a separate question.

Comment: ok I will post it